# Javascript CAML Query using DateTime

Tags: 2013, caml-query, date-time

I have the following CAML:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE' />
            <Value Type='User'>473</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Datum' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>2015-06-05T00:00:00Z</Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

In my list I have 8 items, 7 of these have `Author` equals `473` and 2 of these have `Datum` equals 2015-06-05. Whatever value I pass to the `Datum` i always get 7 items.
What is wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that Datum is the internal name of the column? Otherwise it looks correct.

Comment: Yes it is... shouldn't thorw it an exception otherwise?

Comment: try this one <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2015-06-05T00:00:00</Value>

Comment: Nope. The curious thing is that I get 7 items....if the passed date value isn't correct, I should get 0 items. Right?

Comment: It tends to ignore the CAML if the field values aren't correct rather than throwing any error. I'd try downloading the BIWUG CAML Designer and see what it spits out after constructing the query. http://www.biwug.be/resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find out the problem, but with the following workaround I got it:

```
<Where>
<And>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE' />
        <Value Type='User'>473</Value>
    </Eq>
    <And>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Datum' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>2015-06-05 00:00:00</Value>
        </Leq>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Datum' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>2015-06-05 00:00:00</Value>
        </Geq>
    </And>
</And>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the time zone of your server. It is possible that your web time zone and browser time zone differs. You should try these options:

1. Set property [SP.CamlQuery.datesInUtc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245726.aspx) to `false`
2. Set property [SP.CamlQuery.datesInUtc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245726.aspx) to `true` and pass correct value in UTC. For example, if your web time zone is +2 UTC, browser shows date value `2015-06-05 00:00:00`, but real value in SharePoint database is `2015-06-04 22:00:00`

Play with this settings and values.

Comment: I tryied it out, but the result does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LocalTime to UTC convertion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms468441(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Example in pnp js:

```
const yourDateTime = new Date();
const timezone = sp.web.regionalSettings.timeZone;
const dateTimeForCaml = (await timezone.localTimeToUTC(yourDateTime)).toString();
```

Its solve my issue even when I have time zone differences with SharePoint.